# Narrowing down pending changes in TFS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I use Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 5 with numerous third-party extensions such as Telerik, etc.

Recently, all three of my dev systems have started behaving differently where the local TFS store seems to be in use (busy) so making changes to the projects the first time results in a check-out time-out. I almost always have to restart VS before check-in and get-latest operations.

As a result, I end up checking out entire projects before starting work in order to minimize restarts. when checking back in, the pending changes show all projects files of course. The question is, is it possible to narrow down/filter that list to the files which actually have changes? A typical session only changes a few files out of thousands. The rest are unmodified locks. I'd like to know which is which before actually checking in.

any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specifically answer your question - no, there isn't a way to filter the list by what files have changes *because the changes are not determined at that time*.

But you don't need to be concerned about filtering the list - if you check a file in and there were no changes then TFS does an *undo checkout* on it instead.

Comment: Yes I realize only changed files will be pushed but sometimes when you are revisiting your work after a while, it would be good to have that filter.There are often scenarios where you don't want to check in certain changes but don't remember which files they were in. That filter would really help here.

Comment: If there is no way via TFS, I supposed I could write a script to filter files by last modified.

Comment: @RaheelKhan You could always use a [shelveset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx) instead. Or you could spend some time now to avoid a lot of frustration later - just rebuild your dev environments.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out shelvesets. I often switch between machines and this is ideal for keeping in-progress work synced. And yes, I do need to rebuilt the dev env as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

TFS power tools has a undo unchanged command which should clear them all.

Tfpt uu is the command IIRC

https://coding.abel.nu/2013/06/undo-checkout-for-unchanged-items-in-tfs/

Comment: That is a VERY handy tool :). Thank you.